# How do I include an animated fbx-file(or contents thereof) into a 3D-world using a Proxy-DLL?

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, direct3d9

I want to insert an animated 3d object in a fbx-file via proxy-directx-dll into a d3d9 game. I want it to fit in such that light being thrown in the game is affected by it which makes it throw a shadow. I want it to appear and the animation to start when a hotkey is being pressed in a distance of X in front of the player. I want to resize/pan it via hotkey aswell.

What I did:

I read [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/directx/directx8/article.php/c11453/Intercept-Calls-to-DirectX-with-a-Proxy-DLL.htm) and found a well working dll. I went as far as painting a line and a triangle on top of the game's screen. This happens in the present function.

How do I include a fbx-file(or contents thereof) into the 3D-world, which d3d function do need to use and which command includes the object?

Comment: Don't everybody speak up at once!

Comment: Do you mean: "How to load a 3d object" into a 3D world? (just making sure)

Comment: @FlorisVelleman Thanks. What I mean is "How to load a 3d object, that is animated, into a game via proxy-dll and show it + activate it's animation via hotkey". Proxy-dll is a file called d3d9.dll that passes each d3d9 function to the main d3d9.dll but inserts some other code where necessary.

Comment: More replies desired.